# wrong polynomial regression plot

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to use linear and polynomial regression for the data.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model, cross_validation
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

def f(x):
    return np.sin(2 * np.pi * x)

x = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=100)[:, np.newaxis]
y = f(x) + np.random.normal(scale=0.3, size=100)[:, np.newaxis]

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)



poly_model = make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(degree=2), linear_model.LinearRegression())
poly_model.fit(x_train, y_train)



linear_model_1 = linear_model.LinearRegression()
linear_model_1.fit(x_train, y_train)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()

ax.set(xlabel='X', ylabel='Y', title='X vs Y')
ax.scatter(x,y, alpha=0.5, cmap='viridis')
ax.plot(x_test, linear_model_1.predict(x_test), color='green', label='linear')
ax.plot(x_test, poly_model.predict(x_test), color='red', label='poly')

ax.legend()
```

With the above code, I am receiving this image:

[image]

But as you can see, the polynomial regression is not right.

I tried different approaches ( not using `make_pipeline` etc) but with no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, just add a sorting to your `x_test` before passing it to `predict()` function and increase the degree of polynomial to 3:

```
poly_model = make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(degree=3), linear_model.LinearRegression())
```

and

```
x_test.sort(axis=0)
```

with these adjustments I'm getting following plot:
[image]

Comment: Ok,thanks!So, in this situations is better either to avoid line style either to sort before, right?(upvoted)

Comment: Matplotlib tries to construct lines by sequentially connecting values contained in your list. If they are out of order, you may connect points that are on the different sides of your curve. So, sometimes it is sufficient to just sort them along the axis. It may not be sufficient in cases which deal with closed shapes.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can just call plot twice, it will add new line to existing plot. eg:

```
ax.plot(x_test, model1.predict(x_test), color='red', linewidth=2)
ax.plot(x_test, model2.predict(x_test), color='green', linewidth=2)
```

In your case I'd do sth like that:

```
linear_model = linear_model.LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)
poly_model = model = Pipeline([('poly', PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)),
                   ('linear', linear_model.LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False))])

linear_model.fit(x_train, y_train)
poly_model.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

And then:

```
ax.plot(x_test, linear_model.predict(x_test), color='red', linewidth=2, label='linear')
ax.plot(x_test, poly_model.predict(x_test), color='green', linewidth=2, label='poly')
ax.legend()
```

Comment: I am just using one  `model` which creates linear and polynomial objects.So, I can't use `model1 and model2` as you said.I can't understand how to extract the linear and polynomial parts from `model`

Comment: My image is like https://postimg.org/image/l3ix7br1f/. (I tested and with bigger data and I saw the same pattern for polynomial.It goes back and frond instead being a curve)

Comment: I guess ,it is because the poly model contains both linear and poly regression.That's why I was asking how to extract each portin from `model`

Comment: Why are you making a Pipeline for the `poly_model` ?

Comment: @MMF:I thought that this way the model with create 2 objects , one for linear and one for polynomial regression.And then remains to extract each portion of it in order to be able to plot it.That's why I am saying that I am not sure if I am in the right path.

Comment: No. Just create a second model as you did for the linear one and then plot it as suggested here above.

Comment: @MMF:I tried that `poly_model = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)` , then `poly_model.fit(x_train, y_train)`, but when i am trying to plot `ax.plot(x_test, poly_model.predict(x_test), color='green', linewidth=2, label='poly')` it says that `object has no attribute 'predict'`

Comment: @George What in your opinion is wrong with your plot? You consider it wrong because of intersecting lines? Just sort your `x_test` with `x_test.sort(axis=0)` before passing it to `predict()' function.