# wrong plot in logistic regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to implement logistic regression but I am receiving wrong plot.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
sns.set()

x = (np.random.randint(2000, size=400)).reshape((400,1))
y = (np.random.randint(2, size=400)).reshape((400,1)).ravel()

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=0)

logistic_regr = LogisticRegression()
logistic_regr.fit(x_train, y_train)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set(xlabel='x', ylabel='y')
ax.plot(x_test, logistic_regr.predict_proba(x_test), label='Logistic regr')
#ax.plot(x_test,logistic_regr.predict(x_test), label='Logistic regr')
ax.legend()
```

And I am receiving the following plot:

[image]

If I use:

`ax.plot(x_test,logistic_regr.predict(x_test), label='Logistic regr')`

I am receiving:

[image]

Comment: Your regression predicts always `0`, that's why you are having this plot. Your training data is completely random and your target is only made of `0`and `1` and you want it to be a linear regression. So the regression is a line and it predicts either always 0 or always 1.

Comment: @MMF:Hmm.Right!My target must lie between [0,1] since it is the probability.If I try as target `np.linspace(0,1,400).ravel()` it throws `Unknown label type`

Comment: But the problem is that you only have either `0` or `1`. Not values in between. `np.random.randint( )` returns only integers

Comment: @MMF: I have updated my comment

Comment: @MMF:Using the `logistic_regr.predict_proba` should't it find a probability between [0,1] ? Regardless of my target?

Comment: `np.random.rand(400)` must work

Comment: the `.predict_proba` method does not return what you think it does. It returns the probability that your predicted values is actually the true one.

Comment: @MMF:Hmm..Ok.The `np.random.rand(400)` gives again `Unknown label type`

Comment: @George You're probably trying to use `np.random.rand(400)` to generate your class label data. You have to use sequential integer values that denote classes for a multinomial logistic regression, or 0s and 1s for binomial log. regression. So, as MMF said, you could use `np.random.rand(400)` for your input data, but you have to use `np.random.randint(2, size=400)` for your labels, if you have two output classes. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Your graphs and predictions are actually fine for the input data that you're using.

Comment: @nullop:I would expect a sigmoid function from 0 to 1 in y axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you will not get a graph of sigmoid function with your particular choice of data. Your random input makes algorithm to find some separation between classes that will predict probabilities close to 0.5 with variations depending on the randomness of your input. You could get a sigmoid by using an evenly split range of values, one half of which belongs to the first class and the second half belongs to the second class. This way your `predict_proba()` function will output a range of probabilities for the particular class varied from 0 to 1 (I assume that the rest of your code will remain intact):

```
x = np.linspace(-2, 2, 400).reshape((400,1))
y = np.vstack((np.zeros(200), np.ones(200))).reshape((400,1))
```

then generate your graph:

```
ax.plot(x_test, logistic_regr.predict_proba(x_test)[:,1], '.', label='Logistic regr')
```

You will get a sigmoid-shaped plot describing the probability of predicting one of the classes:
[image]

Comment: Ok,thanks!It seems also that without the `'.'` in the plot command the plot is messy!(also if you can help with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41043348/wrong-polynomial-regression-plot. Thanks!

Comment: If you sort your `x_test` array by calling `x_test.sort(axis=0)` before passing it to `predict_proba()` function, you will get a smooth plot.

Comment: Hmm,ok it works!So,it is a good practice to sort things before plotting  I guess

Comment: One question though..If we plot the `logistic_regr.predict_proba(x_test)` and not the `[:,1]` we take 2 sigmoids.Is this how the logistic regression generates the data?Thanks!(upvoted)

Comment: Logistic regression uses sigmoid to map our output into the range of values which are convenient for us to interpret as probability estimates. Sigmoid is just a tool, it is not the purpose of logistic regression. We may not always get a proper sigmoid-shaped output. My example is a very specific case where the probability of predicting one particular class varies from 0 to 1. This allows us to obtain a clear sigmoid shape, but real examples may have a very different graph of predicted values.